# PM2 logs crash with [TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [app] process (change the value with --lines option)

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am working with pm2 logs for a month. It works very good.
Suddenly, when doing `pm2 logs app` (which app is the name of the app),
it return the following error in Terminal:

```
>>>> In-memory PM2 is out-of-date, do:
>>>> $ pm2 update
In memory PM2 version: 2.7.2
Local PM2 version: 2.8.0

[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [app] process (change the value with --lines option)
Aborted
```

Usually it has to show the console log of the Node server.

I am also facing 503 errors when trying to load the pages in browsers.

I have tried to re install pm2 but it did not work.
And as you can guess, I have ran `pm2 update` which updated pm2, but I still receive the same error.

Maybe someone familier with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to update your pm2 after this and respond with a 503 status code means full service is impossible i.e. the Web site is simply unavailable,  generally it is because of some human intervention by the operators of the Web server machine. restart your server once than check it's status again.

Comment: I have un installed pm2, as root. Then I have installed again, as root.
Now when I am running pm2 logs, it works, but when I am running pm2 logs app it gives the error I have mentioned above.

Comment: try this: kill the node.exe process, see this link for more help https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2462

Comment: hey there, the problem is still. maybe someone can solve it?

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `pm2 status` to check correctly name of the app, then use `pm2 logs --lines 50 [your app name]`.